# Check if any of the checkbox is selected in the form

Tags: php, javascript

I want to put restriction on the form submit so it compels the user to select any checkbox first.
Using loop I am printing a checkbox with each record.

```
 <input name="Chk['<?php print $i;?>']" type="checkbox" value="<?php print $ResultArray[$i]['ClientId'];?>" class="c1">
```

on submit I am calling a javascript function but wont be able to perform the required scenario.

Comment: Provide your JS function, too!

Comment: try $('.c1').each({//check here});

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = document.getElementById('Form2');
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
var is_checked = false;
for(var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
   if(inputs[x].type == 'checkbox') {
       is_checked = inputs[x].checked;
       if(is_checked) break;
   }
}
// is_checked will be boolean 'true' if any are checked at this point.
```

Comment: However there is no jQuery tag, so it would be great if you provided another variant in pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can itereate over all the checkboxes in a form like this without needing to use jquery

The argument to the function is the form element {}

```
function checkCheckBoxes(formvar)
{
for (j=0; j<formvar.length; j++) {  
        if (formvar[j].type == 'checkbox') {  
            if (formvar[j].checked == true)
                    count++;            
    }
}
```